# Relationship to content in term view causes duplicate and missing results

Tags: 7, views

I have these terms, nodes and comments. So 'NodeA' and 'NodeB' are tagged with 'Term1'. Both 'NodeA' and 'NodeB' have new comments.

```
Term1
-NodeA (has new comments)
-NodeB (has new comments) 
Term2
-NodeC (no new comments) 
-NodeD (no new comments) 
Term3
-NodeE (no new comments) 
-NodeF (has new comments)
Term4
```

I need to make a view that looks like this:

```
Term1 – new comments!

Term2

Term3 – new comments!

Term4
```

If I make a term view is stars out ok:

```
Term1 

Term2

Term3 

Term4
```

However when I add a relationship 'Taxonomy term: Content with term' then add the field 'Content: New comments' using this relationship, then I get this:

```
Term1
New comments: 1

Term1
New comments: 1

Term2
New comments:

Term2
New comments:

Term3 
New comments:

Term3
New comments: 1
```

I get a result for each node, not 1 result for each term. I also get no result at all for the term with no nodes. Is there a solution within views for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation ("Advanced" menu, "Other" section, "Aggregation" feature) to sum your results and have something like:
Term 1 (5) - New comments
Term 2 (3)

Or you can try having distinct enabled ("Advanced" menu, "Other" section, "Query settings" feature) to show just the distinct results.

Hope it helps